# Create a Wordpress meta box to control the color scheme of each post/page

Tags: css, wordpress, select, meta, box

I'm currently leaning how to create a WordPress meta box with a select tag for controlling the color scheme of each post/page. I want to create a situation where I can use if statements to load an extra CSS file that overwrites the original CSS file colors using the wp_enqueue_style function in functions.php.

So far I used the following code from the WordPress codex for adding the meta box and outputting the value from get_post_meta. The code is currently in the form of a plugin.

Meta Box Code: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```html
<?php

/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

 $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

 foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

  add_meta_box(
   'myplugin_sectionid',
   __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
   'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
   $screen
  );
 }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

 // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
 wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_box', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

 /*
  * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
  * from the database and use the value for the form.
  */
 $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

 echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
 _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
 echo '</label> ';
 echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

 /*
  * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
  * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
  */

 // Check if our nonce is set.
 if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
  return;
 }

 // Verify that the nonce is valid.
 if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_meta_box' ) ) {
  return;
 }

 // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
  return;
 }

 // Check the user's permissions.
 if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
   return;
  }

 } else {

  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
   return;
  }
 }

 /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */
 
 // Make sure that it is set.
 if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
  return;
 }

 // Sanitize user input.
 $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );

 // Update the meta field in the database.
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Value Output: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

```html
<?php 
$my_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( ! empty( $my_data ) ) {
  echo $my_data;
} 
?>
```

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to change the code logic if I decide to replace the input tag with a select tag with options of colors that will determine which CSS file will be used to overwrite the original file.

Thank you for your time!

### Update

After following the advice from patnz, I changed the value output to the following and got it to work. I'll now start intergrating this into my theme. Thanks!

```html
<?php 
$my_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );
// check if the custom field has a value
if( $my_data == val1 ) {
  echo $my_data;
} elseif ($my_data == val2) {
  echo $my_data;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is working so far and you are just wanting to replace the input[type=text] with a select, your select tag will look something like this:

```
//... continued from code above

// JUST REMOVE INPUT TAG - // echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field"...

 echo '<select id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field">';
 echo '<option value="">- select a value -</option>';
 echo '<option value="val1" '.selected("val1",esc_attr( $value )).'" >Value 1</option>';
 echo '<option value="val2" '.selected("val2",esc_attr( $value )).'" >Value 2</option>';
 echo '</select>';
```

- selected() is a WordPress function that compares two values and will add the selected attribute to the option if the values match.

Comment: Thank you! I followed your advice and made changes to the output and got it to work.